# Mysql Connection issue in monotouch

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin.ios

I want to use MySql connector.NET in monotouch and it keeps giving me weird error.

Error is as below:

> Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Could not import type
>   `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' from`MySql.Data,
>   Version=6.3.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"

and:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `object' to`
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

I used the following code to create connection :

```
string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;" + "Database=myDatabas;" + 
                          "User ID=username;" + "Password=myPassword;" +  
                          "Pooling=false;"; 
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection ();
```

please help me on above error.

Comment: it is not enough to understand the problem with your code.. provide more information

Answer (score 2):

Did you include

```
conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
```

?

Comment: Here is the solution then or at least it seems like that or a similar idea: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/29293/compiler-error-with-mysql-connection-in-unity-3-sy.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `MySql.Data.dll` assembly was compiled against the MonoTouch Base Class Libraries (BCL).

The MonoTouch BCL is a superset of the Silverlight API and it does not include everything a full framework does, e.g. not everything from .NET 4.0 is available. That can cause problems when loading assemblies (e.g. for the compiler).

Comment: I added MySql.Data.dll in my project reference , but i'm not sure about compiling the assembly in BCL . How can i compile this DLL in BCL ?

Comment: You need to rebuild the assembly from source in order to compile it against the assemblies that are shipped with MonoTouch. Otherwise it may (or may not) work - if you have the choice of several binaries then select the oldest ones (e.g. an assembly targeting .NET 2.0 has more chance to work that one compiled against .NET 4.0).